# Proof for "equivalence" between mid-points and parallels. Construction using a ruler.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, geometric-construction

Let's say we have a segment with a mid-point. By exploiting that mid-point, and using only a ruler, I can draw a parallel from any point to that segment.
But I  still have to demonstrate that it is a parallel.
So in a first time I'll show you how I draw this parallel, and then **I'll ask for a proof.** In the case that's wrong, provide a proof too.

I can't embed  pics, see links.

At start (see fig 1), we have a segment AB. The mid-point is C (i.e length or AC and CB are same).  We have an arbitrary point D. We want to draw a parallel line to segment AB, that go through point D, using only a ruler.

[image: figure 1 here]

So we draw the half-line AD with origin A and that go through point D (see fig 2). Let's take an arbitrary point E, on that  half-line, but not on AD segment. Then, let's draw segment BE.

[image: figure 2 here]

We draw then segment CE and BD. (see fig 3). This creates a new intersection point, that we call F.

[image: figure 3 here]

Now let's draw half-line AF with origin A and that go through point F (see fig 4). There's a new intersection point between half-line AF  and segment BE that we call G.
Finally let's draw line DG that go through point D and G. Please, **provide proof that line DG  is a parallel to segment AB** (otherwise demonstrate contrary).

[image: figure 4 here]

Comment: What kind of proof do you want.  For example, if you do a shear transformation to your figure 4 based on $AB$ which moves $E$ to be on the perpendicular bisector of $AB$ then it is true by symmetry. Now undo the shear transformation, and it is still true

Comment: Ideally a proof that use basic knowledge, and that I  can present to a math teacher (it's a friend, I'm not anymore at school).  I  thought we could use Thales thereon, or some triangle properties. I  found the proof when I  was young, but I can't manage to demonstrate it again now.

Comment: Do you know Ceva's Theorem?  If you do, then use it to establish $$\frac{ED}{DA}=\frac{EG}{GB}\,.$$

Comment: If not, let $AG$ meet the line $\ell$ parallel to $AB$ passing through $E$ at $M$, and let $BG$ meet $\ell$ at $N$.  Show that $EM=EN$, $\dfrac{ED}{DA}=\dfrac{EN}{AB}$, and $\dfrac{EG}{GB}=\dfrac{EM}{AB}$.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting Ceva's Theorem. (I've just learned it). So when combined with Reciprocal of Intercept Theorem, the demonstration is straightforward.  However, I might have misunderstood  second comment:  when I follow the steps, I see that the points N and E are same.

Comment: @Batominovski I suspect you intended to say $N$ was where $\ell$ meets $BD$ rather than $BG$

Comment: @Henry  Yes, thanks. It was a typo.

Comment: @Mehdi  Please read Henry's comment regarding the point $N$.  My definition of $N$ contained a typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many possible proofs: Batominovski gave a couple in the comments based on classical geometry and I gave another saying "if you do a shear transformation to your figure 4 based on $AB$ which moves $E$ to be on the perpendicular bisector of $AB$ then it is true by symmetry. Now undo the shear transformation, and it is still true."

Here is another, based on vectors from $A$:

- If $AB$ is $\vec{b}$ then $AC$ is $\frac12\vec{b}$
- If $AD$ is $\vec{d}$ and $AE$ is $k\vec{d}$ for some $k$, then $AF$ is $\frac{k-1}{2k-1}\vec{b} + \frac{k}{2k-1}\vec{d}$ as $F$ lies on $BD$ and $CE$
- So $AG$ is $\frac{k-1}{k}\vec{b} + \vec{d}$ as $G$ lies on $BE$ and $AF$
- and thus $DG$ must be parallel to $AB$

Comment: A vector based demonstration is interesting.  But you might be skipping too much steps on your explanation, that you think are trivial.   Especially, how you expressed vector AF as  a combination of vector b and d. Unless this was intended to be guidelines. 

About the shear transformation proof, it looks more intuitive than rigorous to me. I'm unsure, it would be accepted at school.

Comment: @Mehdi The skipped steps are not trivial but they are simple.  For example $AF$ must be $t\vec{b}+(1-t)\vec{d}$ for some $t$ as $F$ lies on $BD$ and also $s\frac12\vec{b}+(1-s)k\vec{d}$ for some $s$ as $F$ lies on $CE$.  Solving this by matching coefficients gives two simultaneous equations leading to $s=2t$ and thus $t=\frac{k-1}{2k-1}$.

Comment: Ok, I  managed to check "quickly" your vector based proof.
But there's probably an other typo,  I  think you meant "G lies on BE and AF". That's not the easiest proof, but  it's fine.

Comment: @Mehdi - thank you for that - edited